# How do I make a method for distance conversion?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create a distance conversion app to learn Swift. I'm planning to create a method to convert all values. How would I start doing that?

If there are other ways I can convert my values, tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var inputNumber = ""
@State private var inputUnit = 0
@State private var outputUnit = 1
@State private var convertedValue = ""

let inputUnits = ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yard", "Miles"]
let outputUnits = ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yard", "Miles"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Enter measurement", text: $inputNumber)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                Picker("Your unit", selection: $inputUnit) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< inputUnits.count) {
                        Text("\(self.inputUnits[$0])")
                    }
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("What unit would you like to convert to?")) {
                Picker("Convert to...", selection: $outputUnit) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< outputUnits.count) {
                        Text("\(self.outputUnits[$0])")
                    }
                }
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    self.calculateConversion()
                }) { Text("Convert") }
                Text(convertedValue)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("How Far?")
    }
}

func calculateConvertedValue() {
    convertedValue = "New converted value."
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at the very useful `Measurement` class

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make an Dictonary [String:Double] with all Units.
And just take 1 meter as the base value and for every other unit the corresponding value which converts to 1 meter.

And then in your method just divide the old value by the double value from the old unit in the dictionary and multiplied by the double value of the unit you want it in.